# Sum Involving Gamma Function

Tags: calculus

I see in a forum could you explain where come from
$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{n! \Gamma (n+1,-1) \binom{k-1}{n}}{e \Gamma (n+1)}=\Gamma (k)$$

Comment: Maybe this equation would help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Properties

Comment: Also $\Gamma(n+1) = n!$ so there is some easy cancellation that takes place.  Maybe there is a typo?

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith I also think there is a typo, because I've been trying to solve this and got nothing but disappointment :P

Comment: Did you check the series to see if it even converges?

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith oh... I commit a rookie mistake and didn't checked convergence first. But it seems that it diverges to $+\infty$ I'm not sure, however we still need the correction.